# How to pass arguments from div elements within a div class to AJAX then PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to pass values of a div to AJAX by clicking on the containing div.     I would like to click on the div class `self` and pass the div class `identity` for each element to AJAX to be used to retrieve data from a PHP program.

How do I pass the text in the div class `identity` element to the `data` in jQuery?

```html
<div class="self">
  <div class="identity">1234</div>
  Helo
</div>
<div class="self">
  <div class="identity">3444</div>
  Helo
</div>
<div class="self">
  <div class="identity">7845</div>
  Helo
</div>
```

```js
$(".self").on("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $.ajax({
    url: "post.php",
    data: {
      id: // need to pass the value for identity here
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json", // The type of data I expect back
  }).done(function(json) {
    $("<h1>").text(json.title).appendTo("body");
    $("<div class=\"content\">").html(json.html).appendTo("body");
  }).fail(function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
    alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
    console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    console.dir(xhr);
  }).always(function(xhr, status) {
    alert("The request is complete!");
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you. will try that just now.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it worked. thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer for you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this
`let id = $(this).children('.identity').text()`;

or `let id = $(this).find('.identity').text();`
But you should trim or parse it to int before you use it. It depends.

```
let identity_id = parseInt(id);
```

I will also suggest you use something like attribute setter.

```
<div class="identity" data-identity = "3444">3444</div>
```

And this by,

```
let identity_id = $(this).find('identity').attr('data-identity');
```

Comment: Thanks, thats another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOM traversal to find the `.identity` related to the `.self` which raised the click event. Specifically, the `find()` method. Then you san use `text()` to get the content. Try this:

```
data: {
  id: $(this).find('.identity').text()
},
```